# using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor while transferring files over the network

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am currently writing a spring batch which is supposed to transfer all the files from my application to a shared location. The batch consists of a single step which consists of a reader which reads byte[], a processor that converts it to pdf and a writer that creates new file at the shared location.

1) Since its an IO bound operation should I use ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in my batch? Will using it cause the data to be lost?

2) Also in my ItemWriter I am writing using a FileOutputStream. My server is in paris and the shared location is in New York. SO while writing the file in such scenarios is there any better or effecient way to achieve this with least delay?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) If you can separate the IO-bound operation into its own thread and other parts into their own threads, you could go for a multithreaded approach. Data won't be lost if you write it correctly.
One approach could be as follows:

- Have one reader thread read the data into a buffer.
- Have a second thread perform the transformation into PDF.
- Have a third thread perform the write out (if it's not to the same
  disk as the reading).

2) So it's a mapped network share? There's probably not much you can do from Java then. But before you get worried about it, you should make sure it's an actual issue and not premature optimization.

Comment: How do i separate it in another thread. Its part of the ItemWriter of the Spring Batch. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the spring-batch part. You'll have to see the documentation for it and whether it allows you to perform multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve the above task by partitioning. Create Master step which returns you the file paths  and slave task with multi-thread with two approach.

1. simple tasklet which would read the file /convert to pdf and write to shared drive.

   Rather than using FileOutputStream use FileChannel with BufferedRead/Write it has much better performance
2. Use Chunk Reader specifically ItemStream and pass it to custom ItemWriter to write to file(Never got chance to write to pdf but I believe at the end of the day it will be a stream with different encoding)

I would recommand the second one, its always better to use lib rather than using custom code